# Name of this month (Date.today.month as name)

Tags: ruby

I'm using `Date.today.month` to display the month number. Is there a command to get the month name, or do I need to make a case to get it?

Comment: Dylan's answer still works as of Ruby 2.5.0

Answer (score 205, accepted):

`Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month]` would give you "January". (You may need to `require 'date'` first).

Can also use `Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month]` which gives "Jan".

Comment: `Date.today.strftime("%B")` is a better way of doing this, imho. And it's not specific to rails. See answer below by leafo.

Comment: @PedroMorteRolo still works for me on Ruby 2.2.0 -- make sure to `require 'date'` first.

Answer (score 128):

You can also use I18n:

```
I18n.t("date.month_names") # [nil, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names") # [nil, "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
I18n.t("date.month_names")[Date.today.month] # "December"
I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names")[Date.today.month] # "Dec"
```

Comment: As I think, this answer is better than others because I18n returns months names in current locale.

Answer (score 85):

You can use `strftime`:

```
Date.today.strftime("%B") # -> November
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#strftime-method

Comment: Just a warning for anyone using Ruby 2, gotta use
`Time.new.strftime("B")`
Today & strftime are stripped from Date

Comment: Not true. Both are in place with [Ruby 2.0](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#strftime-method) and [Ruby 2.1](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#strftime-method). Note, that they aren't available until you `require "date"`, since they're in the std-lib, not core.

Answer (score 16):

If you care about the locale, you should do this:

```
I18n.l(Time.current, format: "%B")
```

Comment: or `I18n.l(Date.new, format: '%B')` to start with January. 
If you want to add months, like having February, use `Date.new + 1.month`

Answer (score 14):

For Ruby 1.9 I had to use:

```
Time.now.strftime("%B")
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Select month with I18n:

```
<select>
  <option value="">Choose month</option>
  <%= 1.upto(12).each do |month| %>
    <option value="<%= month %>"><%= I18n.t("date.month_names")[month] %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```