# refactor an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array called "dates" that looks like this...

```
@dates = [ 
    {:month => 'apr', :start_date => '2015-04-01', :end_date => '2015-05-01'}, 
    {:month => 'may', :start_date => '2015-05-01', :end_date => '2015-06-01'},
    {:month => 'jun', :start_date => '2015-06-01', :end_date => '2015-07-01'},
    {:month => 'jul', :start_date => '2015-07-01', :end_date => '2015-08-01'},
    {:month => 'aug', :start_date => '2015-08-01', :end_date => '2015-09-01'},
    {:month => 'sep', :start_date => '2015-09-01', :end_date => '2015-10-01'},
    {:month => 'oct', :start_date => '2015-10-01', :end_date => '2015-11-01'},
    {:month => 'nov', :start_date => '2015-11-01', :end_date => '2015-12-01'},
    {:month => 'dec', :start_date => '2015-12-01', :end_date => '2016-01-01'},
    {:month => 'jan', :start_date => '2016-01-01', :end_date => '2016-02-01'},
    {:month => 'feb', :start_date => '2016-02-01', :end_date => '2016-03-01'},
    {:month => 'mar', :start_date => '2016-03-01', :end_date => '2016-04-01'}
    ]
```

I'd love to refactor this but it's beyond me. I tried working towards something like this but got lost in the fact that the jan / feb / march dates would be in the next calendar year....

```
@months = I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names").compact.rotate(3).map(&:downcase)

@dates = []
@months.@months.each_with_index do |mon, x|
  @dates << {:month => mon, :start_date => Date.parse(mon).beginning_of_month, :end_date => Date.parse(mon).end_of_month + 1}
end
```

this ALMOST works, but the last three months are in next year. I have a feeling I could something with the index but cannot get my head round it

any ideas?

Comment: You haven't stated what the desired outcome is. Do you want the remaining months in a year? Or do you want a different label if it is in the next year "feb 2016"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but if you provide some example usage or context I can refine my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the year everytime you hit January:

```
ycount = 0
@months.each do |mon|
  ycount +=1 if mon.downcase == "jan"
  date =  (Date.parse(mon) + ycount.to_i.year)
  @dates << {:month => mon, :start_date => date.beginning_of_month, :end_date => date.end_of_month + 1}
end

@dates
# => [{:month=>"apr", :start_date=>Wed, 01 Apr 2015, :end_date=>Fri, 01 May 2015}, {:month=>"may", :start_date=>Fri, 01 May 2015, :end_date=>Mon, 01 Jun 2015}, {:month=>"jun", :start_date=>Mon, 01 Jun 2015, :end_date=>Wed, 01 Jul 2015}, {:month=>"jul", :start_date=>Wed, 01 Jul 2015, :end_date=>Sat, 01 Aug 2015}, {:month=>"aug", :start_date=>Sat, 01 Aug 2015, :end_date=>Tue, 01 Sep 2015}, {:month=>"sep", :start_date=>Tue, 01 Sep 2015, :end_date=>Thu, 01 Oct 2015}, {:month=>"oct", :start_date=>Thu, 01 Oct 2015, :end_date=>Sun, 01 Nov 2015}, {:month=>"nov", :start_date=>Sun, 01 Nov 2015, :end_date=>Tue, 01 Dec 2015}, {:month=>"dec", :start_date=>Tue, 01 Dec 2015, :end_date=>Fri, 01 Jan 2016}, {:month=>"jan", :start_date=>Fri, 01 Jan 2016, :end_date=>Mon, 01 Feb 2016}, {:month=>"feb", :start_date=>Mon, 01 Feb 2016, :end_date=>Tue, 01 Mar 2016}, {:month=>"mar", :start_date=>Tue, 01 Mar 2016, :end_date=>Fri, 01 Apr 2016}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `I18n.l` to localise the date abbreviation instead.

```
def format_months(start_date = Date.today, months = 12)
  start_date = start_date.beginning_of_month
  months.times.map do |m|
    starts = start_date + m.months
    {
      mon: I18n.l(starts, format: '%b'),
      start_date: starts,
      end_date: starts.end_of_month
    }
  end
end
```

You have not quite stated what is is you are trying to do but using `Date.parse(mon).end_of_month + 1` to get the end date does not seem to make much sense as we all can agree that a month ends on the last day (28-29-30-31st) not on the 1st of the following month.

```
irb(main):004:0> pp format_months
[{:mon=>"Oct", :start_date=>Thu, 01 Oct 2015, :end_date=>Sat, 31 Oct 2015},
 {:mon=>"Nov", :start_date=>Sun, 01 Nov 2015, :end_date=>Mon, 30 Nov 2015},
 {:mon=>"Dec", :start_date=>Tue, 01 Dec 2015, :end_date=>Thu, 31 Dec 2015},
 {:mon=>"Jan", :start_date=>Fri, 01 Jan 2016, :end_date=>Sun, 31 Jan 2016},
 {:mon=>"Feb", :start_date=>Mon, 01 Feb 2016, :end_date=>Mon, 29 Feb 2016},
 {:mon=>"Mar", :start_date=>Tue, 01 Mar 2016, :end_date=>Thu, 31 Mar 2016},
 {:mon=>"Apr", :start_date=>Fri, 01 Apr 2016, :end_date=>Sat, 30 Apr 2016},
 {:mon=>"May", :start_date=>Sun, 01 May 2016, :end_date=>Tue, 31 May 2016},
 {:mon=>"Jun", :start_date=>Wed, 01 Jun 2016, :end_date=>Thu, 30 Jun 2016},
 {:mon=>"Jul", :start_date=>Fri, 01 Jul 2016, :end_date=>Sun, 31 Jul 2016},
 {:mon=>"Aug", :start_date=>Mon, 01 Aug 2016, :end_date=>Wed, 31 Aug 2016},
 {:mon=>"Sep", :start_date=>Thu, 01 Sep 2016, :end_date=>Fri, 30 Sep 2016}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an object to build the array of hashes. That's easy to maintain and modify:

```
require 'date'
class Month

  attr_reader :date

  def self.between(start, finish)
    months = []
    month = new(start)
    while month.start_date <= finish.to_date
      months << month
      month = new(month.date.next_month)
    end
    months
  end

  def self.month_hashs_between(start, finish)
    between(start, finish).collect &:to_hash
  end

  def initialize(date)
    @date = date.to_date
  end

  def month
    date.strftime('%b').downcase
  end

  def start_date
    @start_date ||= Date.new(date.year, date.month, 1)
  end

  def end_date
    @end_date ||= start_date.next_month
  end

  def to_hash
    {
      month: month,
      start_date: start_date.to_s,
      end_date: end_date.to_s
    }
  end

end

start = Date.new(2015, 04, 01)
finish = Date.new(2016, 03, 01)

p Month.month_hashs_between start, finish
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide example output or what it's used for but what I'd normally do is create a simple value object. We can also leverage Ruby's `Date` and `Range` objects to do most of the heavy lifting.

```rb
require 'date'

class DateRange

  def self.import dates
    dates.map do |d| 
      self.new Date.parse(d[:start_date]), Date.parse(d[:end_date])
    end
  end

  def initialize start, finish
     @range = Range.new start, finish
  end

  def month
    Date::MONTHNAMES[start.month]
  end

  def mon
    month[0..2]
  end  

  def include? date
    @range.include? date
  end

  def start
    @range.begin
  end

  def finish
    @range.end
  end

  def to_s
    "#<#{self.class.name} #{start.iso8601}..#{finish.iso8601}>"
  end

end
```

We use `start` and `finish` because `begin` and `end` are reserved words in Ruby, `Range` can use them because it is implemented in C. We could delegate to the Range object or use the Range object directly, but this value object lets us expose only the interface we want.

I exposed the `include?` method which can be used to check if a given date is between the start and finish points, since that's the sort of thing people like to do with date ranges.

Also, we use the `MONTHNAMES` constant defined on `Date` to give us the month name, or the short_month name, which is just the first 3 letters of the month, if you're into that.

This code can be used as a starting point for any value object in a system, remove the stuff you don't need, add stuff you want.

Additionally, I've included an `import` method on the class which will read in your `@dates` array and return a collection of `DateRange` objects.

---

**References**

- [Name of this month (Date.today.month as name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844253/name-of-this-month-date-today-month-as-name)
- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html